# Is it possible to have shell access to Trusted Certificates

Tags: security, https, python

I have an Android Application that launches Python via JNI. Inside of Python I have web requets that I make, some need to be secure. I can configure the APK to be able to access a User CA certificate, but the problem comes in when trying to make a web request from Python.

If I manually copy the PEM file into my app space and load that, I can make SSL calls in python without a problem, but trying to use the OS installed credentials is where I'm having problems. Is there any way in which I can load or use the certificates that have been installed? I would need to be able to use or access them from the shell.

Comment: If you start python via JNI python is running within the app process? Anyway please note that (app+python) programming questions are better suited on stackoverflow.com. BTW: You can make a virtue out of "necessity" to add your own certificate to python: Just call it root ca/certificate pinning and you have a security feature ;)

Comment: I've posted a question to SO with no responses for a few months. I figured I'd post something here as more of a "Can I access these from outside of Java" type of thought process. Is there a folder on the device I can cat or try to load trusted certs from.  Similar to what was mentioned here
https://github.com/yan12125/python3-android/#ssltls

Comment: And yes, python is running within the app process

Comment: Directly accessing the certificate store is not a good idea as it may change in future Android versions. I would use the Java app, [list all root CA certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458046) and convert them in a format that can be used by Python.

Comment: @Robert So once I can list all the CA, can you point me in a direction of how I would use this to create a PEM?  I see how maybe I could do it with openssl, but not sure how to do it all from java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313020/write-x509-certificate-into-pem-formatted-string-in-java

Comment: @Robert in running some of these things, do you know if the User Certificates are available in the KeyStore object, or do I need to access them through KeyChain?

Comment: I have not tried it but in my understanding the user certificates are automatically "mapped" into the `AndroidCAStore` in case the app that is requesting this store is configured to use user certificates via [Network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I have managed to get what I want working.